# TexStudio forward- and inverse search with build in and Sumatra PDF

Tags: sumatrapdf, search

There is so much about forward- and inverse search in the net - first it worked with the configurations I found online. But now it does not even work with the build in Viewer after deleting the ini to go back to the standard option.

My setup: Windows 10, TexStudio, Build in Viewer , Sumtra PDF. 
Under Commands, External PDF Viewer I put: "C:/Program Files (x86)/SumatraPDF/SumatraPDF.exe" -reuse-instance -inverse-search "\"C:\texstudio/texstudio.exe\" \"%%f\" -line %%l" -forward-search "?c:am.tex" @ "?am.pdf"

It sill jumps to random places - with both viewers. What option do I need?

(I also fixed my name of a .tex file that included in _ to -. No change to the better.)

Answer (score 7):

I found [Alper Yazar's blog](https://www.ayazar.com/nb/kb/215-2-19969727-texstudio-sumatrapdf-search-link/) helpful. Below is a brief summary:

**Step 1**. Open configurations - TexStudio >> Options >> Configure TeXstudio...
**Step 2**  Commands >> External PDF Viewer:

```
"C:\Program Files\SumatraPDF\SumatraPDF.exe" -reuse-instance %.pdf
```

**Step 3a.** Build >> PDF Viewer >> External PDF Viewer

**Step 3b.** Build >> User Commands >> Add

```
user0:Forward Search
dde:///"C:/Program Files/SumatraPDF/SumatraPDF.exe":SUMATRA/control/  [ForwardSearch("?am.pdf","?c:am.tex",@,0,0,1)]
```

**Step 4.** Shortcuts >> Menus >> Tools >> User: change current shortcut to F2

**Step 5.** SumatraPDF >> Settings >> Options >> Set inverse search command-line

```
"C:/Program Files/texstudio/texstudio.exe" "%f" -line %l
```

**Notes:** (1) Please adjust paths according to your installation; (2) do not forget quotation marks in step 5; (3) I used SumatraPDF v3.2 64-bit and TeXstudio 3.1.1; (4) in TeXstudio tex-code press F2 to jump to SumatraPDF [forward-search], in SummatraPDF double-click in text to jump to TeXstudio [inverse-search]; (5) if needed: TeXstudio has forward and inverse search, i.e. (a) undo step 3a [use internal viewer] (b) right-click in tex code and select "Go to PDF" (c) in PDF right-click + Go to Source

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 4):

The option "Set inverse serach command-line" in Sumatra seems to be hidden by default and only shows up after first using it.
Just insert a line with:

> InverseSearchCmdLine = "C:/Program Files/texstudio/texstudio.exe" "%f" -line %l

Unfortunately not enough reputation for a comment.

Answer (score 3):

I'm working with TeXStudio 3.2.1 and SumatraPDF 3.3.3 on Windows 10.

The instruction at https://www.sumatrapdfreader.org/docs/Use-SumatraPDF-as-a-pre-viewer-for-LaTeX-editors seems not working anymore with this new TeXStuido version. A possible solution to fix it is to use single quote `'` to quote the argument of `-inverse-search` instead of double quote`"`, and replace any `\"` with `"` which is not recognized by TexStudio anymore.

For example, the path to the executables for TeXStudio and SumatraPDF respectively are:
`C:\Program Files\TeXstudio\texstudio.exe`
`C:\Users\demouser\AppData\Local\SumatraPDF\SumatraPDF.exe`

Then, the full caller to fill in the **External PDF Viewer** in TeXStudio > Options > Configure TeXStudio > Commands is:
`"C:\Users\demouser\AppData\Local\SumatraPDF\SumatraPDF.exe" -forward-search "?c:am.tex" @ -inverse-search '"C:\Program Files\TeXstudio\texstudio.exe" "%%f" -line %%l' "?am.pdf"`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Best answer, it (still) works, and all the other answers either don't work or are unnecessarily complicated.

Answer (score 0):

The following -- rather simple -- setup works for me. In TeXstudio, under `Options > Configure TeXstudio > Commands`, I set `External PDF Viewer` to

```
C:/Program Files/SumatraPDF/SumatraPDF.exe" -forward-search "?c:am.tex" @ "?am.pdf"
```

and in SumatraPDF, under `Settings > Options`, I set `Set inverse search command-line` to

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\TeXstudio\texstudio.exe "%f" -line %l
```

This works even for filenames containing dashes, underscores, spaces, umlauts and other such things. You may need to adjust those paths, of course.

Answer (score 0):

There is some problem with using " symbol in TeXStudio config.
So we can use the following solution: move it to bat-file.

Create file `runSumatraWithInverseSearch.bat` at the same folder with `texstudio.exe`:

```
@ECHO OFF
"C:\Program Files\SumatraPDF\SumatraPDF.exe" -forward-search "%1" %2 -inverse-search "\"%~dp0texstudio.exe\" \"%%f\" -line %%l" "%3"
```

(you can use relative path: `"%~dp0..\SumatraPDF\SumatraPDF.exe"`)

Then TeXStudio Commands->External PDF Viewer set to

```
"[txs-app-dir]/runSumatraWithInverseSearch.bat" "?c:am.tex" @ "?am.pdf"
```

How does it work? `[txs-app-dir]` — is the path to texstudio.exe file. runSumatraWithInverseSearch.bat — is out bat-file with enought " symbols.
We pass tex-file name, line number and pdf-file names to bat-file.