Reusing open document instance in Sumatra PDF with TeXStudio
Let me first start by saying that I am not interested in forward/reverse search.  I actually got that working at long last from some of the various posts on the web and after sorting out the changes in the use of quotes in command line strings.  But I set out to do one simple thing: to get Sumatra to update the present and open instance of a .pdf file when I click the External Viewer button in the upper left corner of TeXStudio's internal viewer. This works practically out of the box with LyX; when I compile a document, the open instance of the .pdf file is automatically updated in Sumatra.  I just want the same functionality in TeXStudio.  I am not sure what is going on behind the scenes for this to work (nor why Adobe never implemented this, much to their detriment, IMO).  Is it DDE commands?  Or does Sumatra detect changes to the .pdf when it is overwritten and update accordingly?
Anyway, this ought to be a subset of the forward/inverse search functionality, which I do not need but have already found and gotten to work. I only need the document to update in the open viewer with each compile.  I have searched the web extensively and all the posts seem to be related to search.  Only one (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/640770/224317) actually works with the most recent releases of these two applications, and it needed -reuse-instance added to the command string.  So if you point me to an existing post, it will likely be one I have already seen and tried.  And, again, I do not want to search; only update.  And it is not enough to just insert -reuse-instance into the command string (leaving out the segments associated with -forward-search and -inverse-search) as one would hope: I have already tried that. Thanks for any help.

Can you please correct your title? Is it "R using ..." or "Reusing ..."? Probably the latter ...

@MS-SPO Indeed.  Thank you!

Thanks. We've all been there ;-)

you may (I emphasise 'may') be looking in the wrong place. for at least some viewers, you need to configure this in the pdf viewer and I think that you would always have to do at least some config on the viewer side. so the reuse-current-instance thing is probably on the editor side. but the update-on-file-change thing is probably on the viewer side. at least, that is how it works for combinations I'm familiar with. does adding the --resuse... thing make any difference? if it stops multiple copies opening, but the open copy doesn't get updated, I'd guess you need to set them separately.
